# Using NancyFx with Php

Tags: php, nancy

Can we use NancyFx with php. 
By deriving the NancyModule class and writting Http request (GET,POST..) in the default constructor?
(as we can do in C#)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Nancy is written in .NET.

PHP is an entirely different language.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably **no**, however - as nancy is written with a .NET language (C#) then you could try to find a project that makes PHP into a .NET language.

http://www.php-compiler.net/
https://ironphp.codeplex.com/

If I were you I'd stick to C# though - but I guess my opinion on the matter does not count.